# Inserting data from a asp.net web application to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert, dataview

I am currently trying to create a project in ASP.NET to create a stock input web application for a cafe which allows users to input stock data from web. I want to know how to save data from browser to SQL Server.

[Screenshot of my current table design / ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72tpD.jpg)
The Item table will hold all information about each item. Stock_Take_Item table will hold the quantity of each item for a stock take, and Stock_Take table will hold the date of the stock take.

I want to be able to present the user with three columns, One for item description (which will already contain the item descriptions in), the second column for Bar Quantity and able the user to input this value and the third Column for Storage Quantity and also allow the user to input this value.

Once a user has filled out the columns for the stock take, will then press a submit button which will trigger c# code to insert these values into the SQL Database.

I hope this isn't too long winded and someone can give me a good recommendation on how to do so. I fully understand my tables may be wrong, and am open to changing them.

Comment: which database is it.. the tagged MySQL or in the title named SQL-server?

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually a question of the specific problem. you rather need to read a very basic tutorial of ASP.net application.

For your convenience, I suggest you to read [This Basic Example](https://codeitbro.com/how-to-create-asp-net-registration-form/) which exactly does what you need and just the table name and field names differ. I suggest you read this up first and then come here for very specific questions.